# jQuery UI droppable & sortable & dragable

Tags: jquery, user-interface, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm building a list of sortable items.

In this sortable list, their is a block, to each block we have elements that we can drag only to the block.

How can I disable to add them to the sortable list as new block?

I have uploaded my code to here: http://jsfiddle.net/zz9C7/

You can see the element "Text" that can be drag to each block "Drag element here".
But also can be drag as a new block to the blocks (sortable) list - how can I disable this?

You can see that we can sort the blocks list, when you hover a block, at the top left corner we have an icon that we can move this block in the sortable list.

Thanks

Edit: Nevermind... I change the connectToSortable in the draggable element. And now it's OK.